# Spartacus v2 Storefront - Header Navigation customisation/restructure

Tags: spartacus-storefront

we are using Spartacus 2 lib in our project, and we want to customise (by restructuring the HTML) the navigation from:

[OOTB Navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ova9z.png)

to this:

[New Nav Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DEdW.png)

Basically putting the Original level 1 nav links inside **Shop Cameras** link.

Can this be achieved by ng-template alone? Or do we need to create another component and call the service that retrieves the nav items again?

Comment: What do you think about arranging the cms data for the navigation links so it will be rendered as you wish?

Answer (score 0):

As @platonn suggests, it is recommended to use the CMS to build content. Hardcoded content can only be added, translated and maintained by developers and requires development testing, deployments, etc. Using a CMS gives you runtime flexibility by business users.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys - Platonn and tobi-or-not-tobi. But what if I have to totally redesign the mega menu? Adding more items under a level 1 navigation (with optional images) in the flyout, and separated by multiple columns. What's the best approach, should I create a new navigation component in this case?

Comment: A new component is likely the best in that case indeed.